# could not connect to redshift database on VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to connect to Redshift database from SQL Workbench/J using Redshift driver which i downloaded from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html. I am getting below error while connecting:
`[Amazon](500150) Error setting/closing connection: Connection timed out:connect.`
I have added below tcp rules to allow connections in security groups:
[Security Group TCP rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRCT9.jpg)
refering this question : [Another question on could not connect to Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842720/cant-connect-to-redshift-database)

 I have tried to connect to Redshift using all three jdbc drivers provided by Amazon still I am unable to connect to Redshift database.

Could anyone please help me resolving this issue.Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Did you enable the "Publicly Accessible" flag when you created the Redshift cluster?

Comment: Yes Mark, i have enabled the flag in "Additional Configuration" tab while setting up the database