# Amazon 500150 : Unable to connect to Redshift Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-redshift

I followed all the steps mentioned on [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-using-workbench.html)
to connect to `Redshift` through `Workbench J`.

I am not using `SSH` to connect, so have left `SSH` settings alone.

When I select Security after selecting `Redshift`, I see :

> Your account does not support the EC2-Classic Platform in this region. Cluster Security Groups are only available when the EC2-Classic Platform is supported. Instead, use VPC Security Groups to control access to your clusters. Go to the EC2 Console to view your VPC Security Groups. For more information, see Amazon Redshift Documentation on Supported Platforms and Managing Clusters in VPC.

My cluster is under a Security Group which has the following Inbound rule :

```
Type: Redshift
 
Protocol: TCP

Port Range: 5439

Source: Custom 0.0.0.0/0 (Experimental, just to test, 
                          I will replace this with my IP address)
```

When I do a `Netstat` on the host from my machine with `-Pn`. I get a

```
Host is up.
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
5439/tcp filtered unknown
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.22 seconds
```

I have already gone through several similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842720/cant-connect-to-redshift-database) and none of these is working for me.

Comment: Can you show us your Redshift configuration? It could be a setting like `Publicly Available` that is causing you grief.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check your Security Group settings:

1. In the Redshift console, go to the `Configuration` tab.
2. Click on the link next to `VPC security groups`

   - Should take you to `Security Groups` in the EC2 console *with the correct security group selected.*
3. Select the `Inbound` tab for the security group and click the `Edit` button (a dialog box opens).
4. In the dialog box, click the `Add Rule` button then:

   - Select `Redshift` from the `Type` dropdown menu
   - Select `Anywhere` from the `Source` dropdown menu

     - **Come back and change this to `My Ip` once your connection works!**
   - Click the `Save` button (the dialog closes)
   - You now have 2 new Redshift rules (`0.0.0.0/0` AND `::/0`)

Then in SQL Workbench's "Select Connection Profile" dialog:

1. Click "Manage Drivers" at the bottom left and to add the [Redshift JDBC driver](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html#download-jdbc-driver).

   - SQL Workbench configures these automatically but check that `Classname` is *like* `com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver` and `Sample URL` is `jdbc:redshift://host:port/name_of_database`.
2. Next, configure the connection

   - Select the new `Driver` you just created from the drop down.
   - Copy the `JDBC URL` from the Redshift console Configuration tab and paste it into the `URL` field.

     - **Must use the correct port**: `jdbc:redshift://my-cluster.asdfgh5jk8.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:`**5439**`/my-db`
   - Add your `Username` and `Password`
   - Test the connection! (Bottom right)

Please let me know in the comments if this doesn't work for some reason and I'll help you get it working.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for your answer. I am connecting to port 5439. The Netstat command was run on the wrong port. Sorry for that, correct output of nmap is Host is up.
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
5439/tcp filtered unknown
I am already following everything you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: Hi Aaditya, I added some instructions for adding the rules to the correct security group. Can you try them and let me know how it works out?

Comment: Hi Joe, I have the same problem with connecting to Redshift. I've setup all according your description, but still cannot connect.

after clicking Test button SQL Workbench returns: 

_[Amazon](500150) Error setting/closing connection: Connection refused: connect_

- credentials are correct