# Connection refused when attempting to connect to cluster in private VPC from local PC

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-redshift

Redshift noob here coming from BigQuery. I have no experience with networking/CIDR/Firewalls/Routes/VPC.

I am trying to connect to my redshift cluster (single node) from my local computer using the python package `psycopg2`. 
When I try to connect, I get the error:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "my-cluster.some-random-stuff.us-east-2.redshift.amazonaws.com" (172.31.xx.xxx) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5439?
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842720/cant-connect-to-redshift-database/19861418#19861418) post, I added the above private IP address (172.31.xx.xxx) as well as my local IP address to the security group inbound Rules (`VPC > Security > Security Groups`), but that didn't work.

I also followed [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cannot-connect-redshift-cluster/) documentation, and added the routes `0.0.0.0/0` and `::/0` in my routes table. This didn't help either.

What am I missing?

Here is my code:

```
def connect_redshift():
    client = boto3.client('redshift', region_name=REGION_NAME)

    credentials = client.get_cluster_credentials(DbUser=USER,
                                                   DbName=DATABASE_NAME,
                                                   ClusterIdentifier=CLUSTER_ID,
                                                   AutoCreate=False)

    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(
            host=HOST,
            port=PORT,
            user=credentials['DbUser'],
            password=credentials['DbPassword'],
            database=DATABASE_NAME
        )

        return conn

    except psycopg2.Error:
        logger.exception('Failed to open database connection.')
        print("Failed")
```

Using the `aws configure`, I added my access key ID, and my secret key. I have `AdministratorAccess` permission.

Comment: This could be due to one or more network configuration issues, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-refusal-failure-issues.html for some troubleshooting tips. However you are probably going to need the assistance of someone familiar with your network, including local network firewall configuration and AWS VPC setup.